# UIImageView cropped being displayed wrong on device

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage

I have an image and i am cropping part of it. The problem is that in the simulator it is displayed correctly, but on the device it is much more zoomed in. It's quite a bit difference. What am i doing wrong? (first image is from the simulator and second from the iphone device)

```
// create bounds and initialise default image 
CGRect imageSizeRectangle = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300);
UIImage *df_Image =  [UIImage imageNamed:@"no_selection.png"];
self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageSizeRectangle];
[imageView setImage:df_Image];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];

//crop image 
CGRect test = CGRectMake(0, 0, 150,150);
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([photo.image CGImage], test);
UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]; 
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

[image: This is how it is displayed on the simulator (correctly)]

[image: How it looks on the device]

Comment: Is your iPhone simulator set to `iPhone (Retina)`? You can check in `Hardware->Device`

Comment: Just checked and no, its set on iphone

Comment: Are you testing on an iPhone 4/4S? If so, set your simulator to retina and see if they behave differently.

Comment: Just checked, if i turn on retina display on the iphone simulator i get the same result as on my device. Is it possible to turn off the retina display on the iphone? or how could i fix this?

Comment: I posted an answer, hopefully it'll be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that retina devices are 2x the size of normal devices. You could check if the device is retina or not with the following method;

```
+(BOOL)iPhoneRetina{
return ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(displayLinkWithTarget:selector:)] && ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0))?1:0;
}
```

And increase/decrease the size of your rect according to the `BOOL` value returned.

Note* `displayLinkWithTarget:selector:` is just a random method that works in iOS 4.0+ but not previous versions. You don't need to pay much attention to it.

Edit*

```
CGRect rect;
if([self iPhoneRetina]){rect = CGRectMake(0,0,300,300);}//Retina
else{rect = CGRectMake(0,0,150,150);}//Non retina

//Then the rest of your code
```

Comment: Thank you, but where do i put the methon under? i'm assuming app delegate and i just call it to false so it sets the retina to false?

Comment: You can't "Turn off" retina display, this method just checks if it is retina or not, you have to then work with either 2x the size, or normal size.

Comment: I see, what is the general fix for this? do i just downscale my images by 1/2 so that they are display correctly on my device?

Comment: Try my update, it should return the same image everytime, except the size will be different.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to get the number `CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]?[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]:1.0;` and then multiply with `rect = CGRectMake(0,0,150*scale,150*scale);`?  That way you'll still crop correctly for scales other than 1.0 and 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to simplize your code you may use

```
CGRectMake(0,0,[UIScreen mainScreen].scale*150,[UIScreen mainScreen].scale*150)
```